# How to send raw Frame using python

Tags: python, sockets, scapy

I have a raw ethernet Frame that i want to send

How should i do that? i tried to send hex values of a frame but i still cant control packet header that contains src/dst address and ports

```
import socket

# the public network interface
HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
addr = ('46.165.204.237', 10000)

# create a raw socket and bind it to the public interface
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_IP)
s.bind((HOST, 0))

netpacket = '\xDE\xB0\x7B\xE5\xA7\xCD\x4C\x17\xEB\x07\x0D\xBC\x08\x00\x45\x00\x00\x92\x68\x94\x40\x00\x78\x06\xDC\x94\x2E\xA5\xCC\xED\xC0\xA8\x01\x02\x27\x10\x07\xC8\x04\xD7\xEA\xEA\xC3\x2A\x4E\xA2\x50\x18\x01\x02\x39\xB0\x00\x00\x3C\x3F\x78\x6D\x6C\x20\x76\x65\x72\x73\x69\x6F\x6E\x3D\x22\x31\x2E\x30\x22\x3F\x3E\x3C\x50\x61\x63\x6B\x65\x74\x3E\x3C\x6F\x70\x65\x72\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x3E\x33\x3C\x2F\x6F\x70\x65\x72\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x3E\x3C\x64\x61\x74\x61\x3E\x33\x24\x30\x24\x30\x24\x30\x24\x30\x24\x30\x3C\x2F\x64\x61\x74\x61\x3E\x3C\x65\x78\x74\x64\x61\x74\x61\x3E\x3C\x2F\x65\x78\x74\x64\x61\x74\x61\x3E\x3C\x2F\x50\x61\x63\x6B\x65\x74\x3E'
#netpaket = netpacket.encode('UTF-8')
s.sendto(netpacket.encode('UTF-8'), addr)
```

Is there in Python a function like sendRaw() or sendRawFrame()?

I know scapy can handle this, but i need to do that many many times, and every time with various payload data. How scapy can be automated? I mean python script that launch scapy creates packet with some payload and send it.

```
scapy.py
packet1 = IP(dst='46.165.204.237')/TCP(sport=1992, dport=10000)/'<?xml version="1.0"?><Packet><operation>99</operation><data><![CDATA[8 fast]]></data><extdata><![CDATA[]]></extdata></Packet>.'
send(packet1)
```

The goal for it is to send packet from a port that already in use. If there a better solution for that problem?

Offtopic: maybe someone knows how to send packets through the Open socket id in windows (not only in python)?

Comment: scapy can be easily automated from python just take a look at the documentation.

Comment: Thanks Steve, i did not think it would be so easy! =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide Scapy with raw input by using the `Raw` layer.

```
netpacket = Raw('\xDE\xB0...')
```

To send packets at the ethernet layer - see the [documentation for `sendp`.](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html#sending-packets)

```
sendp(netpacket, iface="eth1")
```